# Change last element in list

Tags: clojure

I have a nested list: (def mylist '(+ '(+ 1 2) 3))

When I eval it, I get 6 as expected: (eval mylist)

How can I change the last element (3)? I'd like to get a list like this:

```
(+ (+ 1 2) 4)
```

I've tried

```
(list (butlast mylist) 4)
```

but it yields this:

```
((+ (+ 1 2)) 4)
```

i.e. the first part is nested in a list itself. How can I fix it? I'm building up that list datastructure recursively and at a later point I'll evaluate it via the eval function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(concat (drop-last mylist) '(4))
```